# Button created via jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, html, button

I appended a button to a div box, but I cannot apply a click functionality to the new button. In the given example I want to change the color of the div box through a button click.

[**js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZS/)

HTML

```
<ul id="box"></ul>
<button id="add" type="button">Add button!</button>
```

jQuery

```
$("#add").click(function() {

    $("#box").append(' <button class="color" type="button">change color!</button> ');
});


$(".color").click(function(){
    $("#box").css("background","red");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZS/8/)***

This is a classic case of event delegation. Since you created the button dynamically using jquery, the `click` event you've written won't fire. You have to handle as below using `.on()`

Use,

```
$(document).on('click', '.color', function() {
    //Do something
});
```

Note: Using `document` as the parent is bad in most cases & it affects performance because this event searches throught the whole document for the required class `color`. So, replace `document` with the closest parent which *is always present in the DOM (static)*. May be in your case it is `$('#box)`

```
$('#box').on('click', '.color', function() {
    //Do something
});
```

Comment: Do not quote the document, and do not delegate to the document level when #box is clearly the parent of the insterted element.

Comment: That is why `.live()` was deprecated. Traversing recursively from the document is just slow and pointless in this case.

Comment: @adeneo & Matthew: absolutely. I was writing it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Proper creation solves the issue with delegation :

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var button = $('<button />', {
        'class': 'color',
        type   : 'button',
        text   : 'change color!',
        on     : {
             click: function() {
                   $("#box").css("background","red");
             }
        }
    });

    $("#box").append(button);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZS/3/)

to delegate instead, and keep using the strings, do:

```
$('#box').on('click', '.color', function() {
    $("#box").css("background","red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a live delegation for this:

```
$("#box").on('click', '.color', function(){
    $("#box").css("background","red");
});
```

When the page loads, there is no element with class `.button` so there is no event binded to that element. with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) it will bind live to the element.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZS/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you have use the event delegation to apply events to the dynamically created elements

try this

```
$("body").on("click",".color",function(){
    $("#box").css("background","red");
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZS/6/

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to add any event to html which is not added in DOM
Step 1: add button to DOM
Step 2: add click event to the button

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var newButton = $('<button class="color" type="button">change color!</button>');
    $("#box").append(newButton);
    newButton.click(clickNewBtn)
});

function clickNewBtn(){
    $("#box").css("background","red");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZS/5/